# Setting up Alarms for AWS IoT Throttling Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-iot

I am using AWS IoT and using the JITP for device/thing registration.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/

When I carry out the load testing, some of the things are not registered. But I don't see any error either.

I feel this might be happening because of the AWS IoT Throttling Limits.
I suspect one of the below APIs calls, throttling is happening.

```
CreateThing
AttachPolicy
AttachThingPrincipal
```

How can I set an alarm to check if for any of this API calls, throttling is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this currently.

Some alternatives:

1. Don't use JITP and call the APIs yourself.

   - The response of the APIs (including throttling) will be returned directly to you. Then you can log when this happens.
2. Connect your devices within the API request [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/limits-iot.html) .
3. Provision your Things (CreateThing, etc.) *before* starting the load test.